# How to display Vuetify select from Rest API

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

how to display Vuetify select from Rest API with the code I have as follows:

Vuetify code:

```
        <div class="mb-4">
          <v-select
            v-model="provinsi"
            :items="provinsi"
            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Provinsi wajib diisi']"
            label="Pilih Provinsi"
            color="accent"
            placeholder="Pilih salah satu"
            :menu-props="{ overflowX: true }"
            attach
            persistent-placeholder
            auto
            required
          ></v-select>
        </div>
```

JS script:

```
  mounted() {
    fetch(
      `https://kanglerian.github.io/api-wilayah-indonesia/api/provinces.json`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((provinces) => {
        var data = provinces;
        var tampung = "<option>Pilih Provinsi</option>";
        data.forEach((element) => {
          tampung += `<option data-reg="${element.id}" value="${element.name}">${element.name}</option>`;
        });
        document.getElementById("provinsi").innerHTML = tampung;
      });
  },
```

Select Veutify appears from the JSON Rest API

Comment: if you're using `document.getElementById` or any DOM method in vue, you need to re-learn vue. your `v-select` has `:items="provinsi"` ... so, you must have a data property called `provinsi` ... that's what you update with key/value pairs

Comment: By the way is this vue2 or vue3 ...

Comment: Thank you, I use Vue 2, could you please write a code example, thanks in advance

Comment: the vue and vuetify documentation has many examples you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning basic from the **documentation** is the best way.

But I will leave this to you just in case.

**For vuetify 2**

Here's a snippet.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
      provinsi: '',
      provinsidata: [],
    }),
    methods: {
      async getData() {
        await fetch(
          `https://kanglerian.github.io/api-wilayah-indonesia/api/provinces.json`
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(provinces => {
          console.log(provinces)
            this.provinsidata = provinces
          })
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.getData()
    },
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <v-select
          v-model="provinsi"
          :items="provinsidata"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Provinsi wajib diisi']"
          label="Pilih Provinsi"
          color="accent"
          placeholder="Pilih salah satu"
          attach
          persistent-placeholder
          auto
          required
        ></v-select>
        
        VALUE: {{ provinsi }}
      </div>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**For vuetify 3**

Here's a  [Demo.](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)